# rvm doesn't set default ruby with zsh

Tags: rvm, zsh

I'm using zsh in OSX with rvm, but it doesn't load the default ruby at login:

in my .zshrc I have

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I've tried to swap those two lines, but still it doesn't work..

(of course in bash it works..)

Comment: I found an error if I start Terminal.app (and not the usual iTerm) it says: /Users/luca/.rvm/scripts/initialize:45: __rvm_cleanse_variables: function definition file not found

Answer (score 12):

The issue is that OMZ generated `~/.zshrc` with hardcoded `PATH`, this makes the shell overwrite it every time this file is read.

There is also a bug in ZSH or some mysterious power that makes ZSH read `~/.zshrc` after `~/.zprofile` - this leads to resetting PATH.

Just comment out the `PATH=...` line in `~/.zshrc` and it should work.

As for the mentioned error - it is supposed to be fixed already, update RVM - `rvm get head` - and open a new terminal ... if it still appears - [open a new issue for RVM](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues).